# Как с помощью Python откомпилировать другой файл .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, cmd, pyinstaller

я написал простой код который создает файл name + ".py" и записал в него маленький код, но я не знаю как можно было бы откомпелировать этот файл, я пытался сделать вот так: `os.system("cd / & cd C:\Sherik & \'pyinstaller -F -w \' + name + \'.py\'")` но не получилось, у меня python 3.8 работаю в Python Idle

вот часть кода:

```
file = open("C:\Sherik/" + name + ".py", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write("print ('Hello world')")
file.write("print ('Hello world')")
file.write("print ('Hello world')")
file.write("print ('Hello world')")   
file.close()
os.system("cd / & cd C:\Sherik & \'pyinstaller -F -w \' + name + \'.py\' & cd /")
```

так же пробовал в `os.system("cd / & cd C:\Sherik & \'pyinstaller -F -w \' + name + \'.py\' & cd /")` менять двойные скобочки на одинарные чтоб во всем коде были одинаковые скобочки но это не помогло

Comment: а вы вместо `os.system` напишите `print` и уведите в чем проблема

Comment: проблему то я увидел переменная name не используеться а так и пишеться + name + ".py" но почему так происходит я не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Хорошим тоном является использовать **полный** путь к файлу, а не только его имя, да еще и без расширения.
Ключ `-w` для `pyinstaller` значит "скомпилировать" в режим "без консоли", поэтому результат работы программы `2.exe` вы не увидете.
Вот полный код:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\'
name = '2.py'
com = f'cd /D {path} && pyinstaller -F -w {name}'

with open(path+name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write("print('Hello world')\n")
    file.write("print('Hello world')\n")
    file.write("print('Hello world')\n")
    file.write("print('Hello world')\n")   

os.system(com)
```

Comment: Файл начал компелироваться, я заменил все директории но ни в одной из них не упоминал рабочий стол но файл скомпелировался на рабочий стол

Comment: @Selasi, исправил